# Как пишется Халкидонский догмат?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Как мы видим, иконоборцы в своей аргументации пытаются исходить из
>   халкидонского догмата.

Халкидонский - с прописной или со строчной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, правильно с прописной, поскольку одноимённый собор и вообще церковные соборы (собрания) пишутся с большой буквы. Не нашёл правила, что сами названия соборов пишутся с прописной, но нашёл, что само слово *Вселенский собор* пишется так. В статье *[Халкидонский собор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80)* в Википедии название пишется с прописной не только в начале фраз. Кроме того, в [английской Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition) оба слова в названии **догмата** пишутся с большой буквы, что однако типично для английского: Chalcedonian Definition.

Comment: Вот Вселенский-то как раз должен писаться со строчной, если следовать общим правилам, а не церковной традиции. При всей неординарности этого события, ВС явление не уникальное.

Comment: Ну а что касается аналогии с названиями Соборов... Очень спорно. То есть не то спорно, что они должны писаться с прописной, а то, что это какое-то единое правило. Разница примерно как между Киевским вокзалом в Москве и "киевским" вокзалом в Киеве. Первое - вне всяких сомнений имя собственное, второе - может стать таковым, только если приобретет самостоятельное значение, пройдя стадию онимизации... У вокзала это вряд ли получится, а вот Догмат эту стадию прошел.

Answer (score 0):

С прописной. Приобрело значения имени собственного. 
Тут как бы еще и "догмат" прописной не потребовал, если ориентироваться на церковные традиции.